# Script runs twice after each iteration of a JSP loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstl, el

```
<div style="width:100%;background-color:  #61b832;border-radius: 10px;color:white;text-align: center">Videos List</div>
<table style="width:100%;"id="videoTable">
    <c:forEach items="${requestScope.userInfo.videoList}"var="video"varStatus="0">
        <script>
            var fullvideoUrl='<c:out value="${video.videoUrl}"></c:out>';
            var videocode='http://www.youtube.com/embed/'+youtube_parser(fullvideoUrl);
            $('#videoTable').prepend('<tr class="appendVideo"><td  style="width:80%;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;"><c:out value="${video.videoDescription}"></c:out></td><td  style="width:20%;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC"><img src="images/fancybox_play-button-icon.png" class="changeVideo" videoId="<c:out value="${video.videoId}"></c:out>" videoUrl ="'+videocode+'"/></td></tr>');
        </script>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
</div>
```

This is what i 'm trying to do but each video gets added twice in the table

Comment: What's wrong, the JS script or the generated HTML page? Show us the output, please

Comment: look in the page source code...is script tag there twice for each video?

Comment: can you check number of times script got added in generated html?

Comment: yes script tag is twice in the source code

Comment: Can you show the full generated HTML? Apparently, there are six script blocks apparent.

Comment: 1)  Show what the resultant HTML looks like; that'll help tease out the problem.  2)  What is that extra `div` doing there?  3)  Have you tried to run this loop (literally as is) without the `.prepend`?  Something simple like an `alert()` to prove that it hits X number of times..

Comment: theres not a problem with for each loop problem lies in JS if i print varStatus under this loop its printing thrice however when i use script to prepend it inside a table its prepending 6 times

Comment: @Makoto same is with alert box it pops 6 times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use a `c:if` as below:

```
    <c:if test="${requestScope.userInfo.videoList.size() >0}" >
      <script>
          $('#videoTable').prepend("1");
      </script>
    </c:if>
```

EDIT:

Not sure why are using `script`. I think you can simply write like this:

```
 <div style="width:100%;background-color:  #61b832;border-radius: 10px;color:white;text-align: center">Videos      List</div>
  <table style="width:100%;"id="videoTable">
   <c:forEachitems="${requestScope.userInfo.videoList}" var="video" varStatus="0">
     <tr class="appendVideo"><td  style="width:80%;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;"><c:out value="${video.videoDescription}"></c:out></td><td  style="width:20%;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC"><img src="images/fancybox_play-button-icon.png" class="changeVideo" videoId="<c:out value="${video.videoId}"></c:out>" videoURL="http://www.youtube.com/embed/${video.videoUrl}"/></td></tr>
   </c:forEach>
  </table>
</div>
```

If you want sorting of the results in reverse, simply sort your `requestScope.userInfo.videoList` using `Collections.sort` in reverse before printing that in the UI. Also if there is any modification required in the URL, perform in the original video list itself.

Comment: this wont help theres not a problem with for each loop problem lies in JS if i print varStatus under this loop its printing thrice however when i use script to prepend it inside a table its prepending 6 times

Comment: @MayankSharma This answer was based on the code snippet you shared with the intention to prepend only once based on the list availability. If have different usage and issue, please share full relevant code.

Comment: @MayankSharma I am not sure, why to use script to display the list when   you are using `c:forEach` tag any way. I advice you to prreproces your video list and then render the screen using JSP scriptlets only.

Comment: actually i have created a regex JS function to get the unique code of each youtube video and in DB i stored the full url of youtube now in order to call this function i put that stuff under script tag

Comment: @MayankSharma In that case, list down the original URLs, then use a `onclick` function to invoke the URLs and use your custom JS function inside it.

Answer (score 2):

This problem becomes some times when you use styles inside your jsp file , and one of those styles contain body tag 
remove any body tag inside Style definition tags and the jsp will work properly .
the body statement look like this :

```
body {
    background-image: url();
}
```

just remove this lines from your script and re-run your page.